# Getting the username inside a model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, audit

I'm trying to implement basic auditing with some of my models (like CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, CreatedBy and UpdatedBy).

The date/time part is done. I'm throwing events on my models when a property is changed (implementing `INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged`) and can update the correspondent fields just fine.

I just need to know how to get the current user name without having to pass it through the controller every time I instantiate or get an existing instance of a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Referencing System.Web and using
>   HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
>   worked like a charm.

I didn't know about it. Thanks.
I do it like this:

```
Membership.GetUser().UserName
```

Which way is quicker?

Comment: Considering User object is already populated in HttpContext, that should be quicker.

Comment: Doesn't make a big difference, since this is a "mostly read" application.

Answer (score 2):

The abstract way of talking about identity is the "principal" - see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818891/819124#819124). I would hope that this code allows you to get the identity without having to know about the login implementation:

```
public static class SomeUtilityClass {
    public static string GetUsername() {
        IPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        IIdentity identity = principal == null ? null : principal.Identity;
        return identity == null ? null : identity.Name;
    }
}
...

record.UpdatedBy = record.CreatedBy = SomeUtilityClass.GetUsername();
```

Comment: I don't want to keep specifying it, so it works better with a subscription to the event and doing it on the model itself. Thanks for the reference tho.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing `System.Web` and using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` worked like a charm.